# Azure DevOps - multiple repo checkout

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Scenario

- My code is one repository and all my dependencies is in another repo (another project) that I need to build my code.

Following is my azure-pipelines.yml

```
# File: azure-pipelines.yml

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  phpVersion: 7.3

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: myLibraries
      type: git
      name: myProject/libraries

steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: myLibraries
  path: libraries

- script: |
    sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php$(phpVersion)
    sudo update-alternatives --set phar /usr/bin/phar$(phpVersion)
    sudo update-alternatives --set phpdbg /usr/bin/phpdbg$(phpVersion)
    sudo update-alternatives --set php-cgi /usr/bin/php-cgi$(phpVersion)
    sudo update-alternatives --set phar.phar /usr/bin/phar.phar$(phpVersion)
    php -version
  displayName: 'Use PHP version $(phpVersion)'
```

When I run my pipeline, I got the following error:

Checkout of repository 'myLibraries' is not supported. Only 'self' and 'none' are supported.,Checkout of multiple repositories is not supported.

references:

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/master/design/multicheckout.md
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#using-other-repositories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text you posted provides the answer:

> Checkout of multiple repositories is not supported.

If you want to use multiple repos in a build, you'll need to do it yourself.

Some options:

- Use submodules or subtrees
- Have a `git clone` step that clones the second repository
- Publish the relevant contents from the second repository to an artifacts feed and restore them as necessary

All of these have upsides and downsides.

Comment: Hi @daniel , how about the  [Multiple Repo checkout](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-yaml/blob/master/design/multicheckout.md). Microsoft doc ? is it outdated? thanks for you help

Comment: @sedrac It's a design document. i.e., a proposal for how that feature **could** be implemented.

Answer (score 24):

Multiple repository checkout is now supported - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#multi-repo-checkout

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: MyGitHubRepo # The name used to reference this repository in the checkout step
    type: github
    endpoint: MyGitHubServiceConnection
    name: MyGitHubOrgOrUser/MyGitHubRepo
  - repository: MyBitBucketRepo
    type: bitbucket
    endpoint: MyBitBucketServiceConnection
    name: MyBitBucketOrgOrUser/MyBitBucketRepo
  - repository: MyAzureReposGitRepository
    type: git
    name: MyProject/MyAzureReposGitRepo

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- checkout: self
- checkout: MyGitHubRepo
- checkout: MyBitBucketRepo
- checkout: MyAzureReposGitRepository

- script: dir $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
```

Comment: I am unable to checkout a repo from a different project.

Comment: But what do the endpoint and name parameters mean? I can't find any examples with actual values

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue, the documentation provided was bit confusing. I got it resolved.

here is my ex:

(for checkout of self repo, need not mention anything in the resources/repositories, we need to mention other repos which we wanted to checkout)

resources:

repositories:

- repository: myrepoAliasname

  type: git

  name: myActualreponame

  ref: refs/heads/mybranchname #I wanted to checkout a particular branch in repo

steps:

```
  - checkout: self

  - checkout: myrepoAliasname (this is the name we gave in resources and it will checkout our mentioned branch of this repo)
```